# Issue with chaining and returning array from Angular Service/Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am trying to create a service that will take a date range, and return an array of weeks.

I am now at the point where I am chaining my service functions, to return the array (it works without the chaining, but I cannot return the array), and it is in this chaining that I am getting an error:  **TypeError: data.map(...).sort(...).then is not a function**.

**This is my service/factory call:**

```
$scope.weeks = GroupDateRangeService.createArray(timeline_data);
```

**This is my service/factory:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('portalDashboardApp')
        .factory('GroupDateRangeService', GroupDateRangeService);

    GroupDateRangeService.$inject = [];

    function GroupDateRangeService() {

        var service = {
            createArray: createArray,
        };

        return service;

        function createArray(data) {

            var arr = data.map(function (s) {

                var week = getWeekNumber(parseISOLocal(s));
                return week[0] + ('0' + week[1]).slice(-2) + ':' + s;

            }).sort()

                .then(function () {
                    createGroupObject(arr);
                })
                .then(function () {
                    createGroupedArray(groupedObj)
                })

            return groupedArray;
        };

        function createGroupObject(arr) {

            var groupedObj = arr.reduce(function (result, value) {

                var b = value.split(':');

                if (!result[b[0]]) result[b[0]] = [];
                result[b[0]].push(b[1]);

                return result;

            }, {});

        };

        function createGroupedArray(groupedObj) {

            // Grab arrays in order of week number. Sort keys to maintain order
            var groupedArray = Object.keys(groupedObj).sort().map(key=>groupedObj[key]);

            // Final set of grouped dates
            console.log(groupedArray.join('\n\n'))

            return groupedArray;

        }

        /* Helper to get the ISO week number of a date
        ** @param {Date} date to get week of
        ** @returns {Array} [year, weekNumber]
        */
        function getWeekNumber(d) {
            d = new Date(+d);
            d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7));
            var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
            var weekNo = Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
            return [d.getFullYear(), weekNo];
        }

        /* Parse ISO 8601 format date string to local date
        ** @param {string} s - string to parse like 2016-12-15
        ** @returns {Date}
        */
        function parseISOLocal(s) {
            var b = s.split(/\D/);
            return new Date(b[0], b[1] - 1, b[2]);
        }
    }

})();
```

**The order of creating the array of weeks is as follows:**

1. createArray(data) then pass the result to
2. createGroupObject(arr) then pass the result to
3. createGroupedArray(groupedObj) return array;

There might be a simpler way to do it, and my approach might be flawed. So I will really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort function in JavaScript does not return a promise, thus you cannot use the **then** function right after its call, and actually you don't even need it. Since all your processing doesn't contain any async calls, you can simply chain your function calls as follows :

```
function createArray(data) {
    var arr = data.map(function (s) {
        var week = getWeekNumber(parseISOLocal(s));
        return week[0] + ('0' + week[1]).slice(-2) + ':' + s;
    }).sort();
    return createGroupedArray(createGroupObject(arr));
};
```

You also need to add a return statement at the end of your **createGroupObject** function otherwise it won't return anything :

```
return groupedObj;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)